# How to make objects ignore certain lights in blender 2.8?

Tags: render-layers, collections

In Blender 2.8 in Cycles, how can you make an object ignore certain lights?

Lets say I have a cube in collectionsCube and a bunch of lights in collectionsLights, how do I stop collectionLights from affecting collectionCube? 
In 2.79 its easy with using exclude in Render layers.

I built a scene in 2.79 with this effect, and brought it into 2.8. It works fine, I just dont see anywhere in the new interface to control this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried render layers in blender 2.8 basically the same thing as 2.79 just a different inter face.

Comment: Render layers is now collections in 2.8 as far as what I've read. Where is render layers in 2.8? Im trying to find where to set layers to exclude other layers.

Comment: Top right corner the 2 pages is to make a new layer. Check box is if the collection is included when rendering. After that go to the compositor and you should  what to to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MNioduPFqtQzB64sqYM_by_aETSST3Mw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: im there already. I see how to exclude a layer from the render. I need to know how to exclude layers from other layers. Im looking for this: http://webnamehere.com/example.jpg

Comment: OOHH thanks for your help Yohello. I just realized what youre saying.